# angular-datatables not sorting when formatting date

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I have an issue in sorting date with angular-datables plugins when I want to format them.
Let me explain : 
When I'm using

```
<td>{{date}}</td>
```

The result is :

[image]

When I'm using :

```
{{date | date}}
```

The result is :

[image]

But when I'm using :

```
{{date | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

The result is :

[image]

Even so I declared it as a date format :

```
_this.dtColumnDefs = [  
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).
    .withOption('type', 'date')
];
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I used something similar from your answer provided directly from DataTables : https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-eu

The plugin is deprecated but is working well for what I want.

Answer (score 3):

We are a rare species, those of us using dd/MM/YYYY format :) The default `date` type is only functional on "valid" date formats, i.e. strings that can be evaluated with `Date.parse()`. European dd/MM/YYYY is not one of those. Before mingling with momentjs and such I think you could solve this very easy by a custom sorting plugin :

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
 "Antt-date-pre": function ( a ) {
    if (a == null || a == '') {
      return 0;
    }
    var date = a.split('/');
    return Date.parse(date[1] + '/' + date[0] + '/' + date[2])
  }
});
```

Usage

```
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).
  .withOption('type', 'Antt-date')
```

small demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/00vQcoeitZlrQkprN58t?p=preview**

Comment: I'm trying to copy your code but using it with :

`this.dtColumnDefs = [  
        DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0)
        .withOption('type', 'date-euro')
    ];`             
But I get no call to the jQuery code ... (note that when I replace withOptions with noSortable(), the sort is not working as expected)

Comment: @Antt You are using `'date-euro'`? If you have renamed `'Antt-date'` to `'date-euro'` it really should work (as in the sample). I do exactly this myself in several apps, just with another naming of course. Sry, dont quite understand the comment about `notSortable()`, if you want the column to be not sortable, but still want to pre sort on that column, you can use `.withOption('order', [[<index>, 'asc']])` or similar in your `dt-options` http://plnkr.co/edit/Wo2gtv9OAPWEZ2Fkem6u?p=preview

Comment: Yes sorry I use 'date-euro' I double check :/  the 'notSortable' thingy was to make sur my dtColumnDefs was called which seems to be the case ...